# Build sklearn from source success but run the DecisionTreeClassifier got ImportError

Tags: python-2.7, build, scikit-learn

I get the source code of sklearn by `git clone https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git`

and run the **make** command in the folder, then all the test are passed.

And then I import the sklearn i build and train the DecisionTreeClassifier model, I got the error

> from ._criterion import Criterion  File
>   "sklearn/tree/_criterion.pyx",line 1, in init sklearn.tree._criterion
>   (sklearn/tree/_criterion.c:12825)  ImportError: sklearn.tree._utils
>   does not export expected C function __pyx_fuse_5safe_realloc

Both on mac and ubuntu, I got the same error. Anyone know about that error?
I'm wondering that if I lost some procedures to build from source.

Comment: I had found the key problem myself: just remove the sklearn I have installed  using pip or other tools. Build the sklearn cleanly. It may because when building sklearn, it will use the sklearn utils or  other tools provided by the old sklearn and this causing the  confused problem.